# Python import syslog on windows

Tags: python-2.7, syslog

I have a python script that is normally run on a unix machine, I am trying to run it on windows. The one snag I have run into is the module syslog. Is there a way that anyone knows that I can get around this on a windows machine, is there an equivalent package for windows? Running python 2.7.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/syslog.html

Comment: You don't need to add comments to your own post - just modify your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create syslog.py and put it somewhere in a python path.
You also can customize it to actually write messages down or send them over network.

My version below. (It misses few functions and constants, so you may need to add some more):

```html
import sys

LOG_EMERG, LOG_ALERT, LOG_CRIT, LOG_ERR, LOG_WARNING, \
LOG_NOTICE, LOG_INFO, LOG_DEBUG = range(8)

LOG_KERN, LOG_USER, LOG_MAIL, LOG_DAEMON, LOG_AUTH, \
LOG_SYSLOG, LOG_LPR, LOG_NEWS, LOG_UUCP = range(0,65,8)

LOG_CRON = 120
LOG_LOCAL0 = 128
LOG_LOCAL1 = 136
LOG_LOCAL2 = 144
LOG_LOCAL3 = 152
LOG_LOCAL4 = 160
LOG_LOCAL5 = 168
LOG_LOCAL6 = 176
LOG_LOCAL7 = 184

LOG_PID = 1
LOG_CONS = 2
LOG_NDELAY = 8
LOG_NOWAIT = 16

def syslog(message):
pass

def syslog(priority, message):
pass

def openlog(ident=sys.argv[0], logoptions=0, facility=LOG_USER):
pass

def closelog():
pass

def setlogmask(maskpri):
pass
```

Comment: I copied your code ;) stole your code, mon

Answer (score 1):

The "[logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)" module should be ideal for what you're looking for, though it may require some rewriting of the code. It also has the advantage that logging is platform independent, so it works on both Windows and *nix, which is always handy.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that didn't involve rewriting the code as this scenario is just for developing on windows locally. It is normally run on linux. And from running into this module import issue I currently don't see a way around that.